# How to get InputStream from underlying process when using Java Process

Tags: java, process, inputstream, processbuilder

I'm not able to get command execution result from Java process.getInputStream() from processes underlying process. That is 'cmd.exe' is called (or any other terminal), then 'mysql\n' is typed, so we start an underlying process (or any other command, like 'sqlcmd'), and then execute any MySQL command inside that internal shell and can't get command execution results from the input stream.

I understand that input stream waits for some termination char for it to be able to be read, but for it it's necessary to exit the MySQL shell (or when main method finishes, it also outputs the results), but I can't do it due to requirements, it's going to be a running REST app.
Can I force somehow to read input stream up to the last point and not close it?
Or maybe any other ideas how to get the command execution result?

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
String line, commandInput;

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("\\bin\\bash");

//        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe");
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));

// entering MySQL shell
commandInput = "mysql -u root\\n";
output.write(commandInput);
output.flush();

// providing command to the MySQL shell
commandInput = "select * from some_table limit 1;\n";
output.write(commandInput);
output.flush();

// can't read the result, input is never ready
while (input.ready()) {
line = input.readLine();
if (line == null) {
break;
}
System.out.println(line);
}

// providing 2nd command to the MySQL shell
commandInput = "select * from some_table limit 1;\n";
output.write(commandInput);
output.flush();

// same here, input is never ready
while (input.ready()) {
line = input.readLine();
if (line == null) {
break;
}
System.out.println(line);
}

// if use exit from MySQL shell, so then of course input is ready to be read
//        commandInput = "exit\\n";
//        output.write(commandInput);
//        output.flush();
//        while (input.ready()) {
//            line = input.readLine();
//            if (line == null) {
//                break;
//            }
//            System.out.println(line);
//        }
System.out.println();
}
```

I've tried to redirect input, output streams to be INHERITED, but also wasn't able to get command results then. I was trying to find a way to read the input stream up to the last point, but wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Scanner to read the process when executing the command, here is my code

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ls"); // 
   Process process = processBuilder.start();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
    while (sc.hasNext()) {            
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work, hangs on sc.hasNext() as it always returns true. Just calling sc.nextLine() also hangs

Comment: Can you post your latest code here?

Comment: If you're working with an application that Returns a command prompt you will need to read up to that prompt. Reading any further will result in the Stream blocking. You could treat the response asynchronously so this blocking didn't matter as much

Comment: @g00se How can I read up to that prompt? When I use `InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());`, it hangs on `(char) input.read()` then (after calling select query). So, I'm not even able to read output char by char

Comment: Let's step back a bit. Why are you running a MySql client app in Java in the first place let alone a REST app?

Comment: To perform some load on a MySQL db local channel. To do that, it's necessary to open MySQL client shell from a terminal. Java is used as MySQL is installed on a couple machines. Also, other DBs may be used.

Comment: Sounds unviable to me but if you were determined I would suggest you read the process output and error stream asynchronously as otherwise it will block at the prompt and therefore block your application's main thread